# MVP in windows forms

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns, mvp

I want to implement MVPO pattern in my windows forms application. As you know there is 1:1 means there is one presenter for one view.

So basicly we can have:

```
public class MainPresenter
{
       IMainView _mainView;
       public MainPresenter(IMainView mainView)
       {
             _myView = myView;
       }
}
```

My question is can one presenter use other presenter so for instance:

```
public class MainPresenter
{
       IMainView _mainView;
       ISomeOtherPresenter _otherPresenter;
       public MainPresenter(IMainView mainView, IOtherPresenter otherPresenter)
       {
             _mainView = myView;
             _otherPresenter = otherPresenter;
       }
}
```

As a reference i went through video tutorial by Robert Marquez. At his 10 video serie at 10th one he used one rpesenter inside other one

[Reference link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0CVJ24nYt5I)

at `35:39` you will see his MainPresenter has dependency to IHelpAboutPresenter.

To me it's logical because if `HelpAboutView` (form) can be opened by button from `MainView` it's logical `MainPresenter` has to have access to `HelpAboutPresenter` which was presented on the video. If not that way how to do so because all the people saying `1:1` and here we have `1 presenter uses other presenter.`

Comment: This is about multiple presenters (not multiple views) in one presenter according to my question.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of a code small to has a cross dependency like that. If you need functionality from another presenter, it is likely the presenters have something in common. So perhaps they should derive from the same base class. Then they can easily share logic without complicating your dependency graph.

```
public class BasePresenter
{
    protected void SharedMethod()
    {
        //Code that you need to call from both presenters
    }
}

public class MainPresenter : BasePresenter
{
    IMyView _myView;

    public MainPresenter(IMyView myView)
    {
        _myView = myView;
    }

    private Foo()
    {
        SharedFunction();
    }
}

public class OtherPresenter : BasePresenter
{

    public OtherPresenter(IMyView myView) : base()
    {
        _myView = myView;
    }

    private Bar()
    {
        SharedMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but imagine you have a button on MainView which when you click it open OtherView. So we have MainPresenter and OtherPresenter. If OtherView is accessible by byutton from MainView, how would you handle this? What i am saying is inject OtherPresenter into MainPresenter. How would you accomplish that other way?

Comment: `BasePresenter` would have all the code needed to display `OtherView`. That way both `MainPresenter` and `OtherPresenter` can present the view. Of course, if both presenters can present that view, you may want to rename it, since it is obviously not tied to `OtherPresenter` if `MainPresenter` can present it too.

Comment: can you add code to show based on the situation from MainView there is a button to show OtherView? That would be helpfull. Or using my link in my post can you look at real code at MainPresenter and say how this other presenter injected can be corrected? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would assert that there isn't anything inherently *wrong* with the approach although one could probably go about it another way.

The "main" view could be acting more along the lines of a [front controller](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/front-controller-design-pattern/).  The pattern is more often associated with web-applications although it may still be applicable to desktop applications.  For instance, the main MDI view may be the *front controller*.

Typically a front controller would have some dispatching mechanism to have individual requests (such as menu clicks in a desktop application, or url-based resources in a web-based application) handled by a specific request handler.  There is therefore a slight indirection that decouples the front controller from the specific implementation.

In the case of the linked video the relationship is just a bit more coupled in that the `About` box request (if I understand correctly) is being handled not by a specific request handler but by the front controller.

What makes this appear odd is the fact that the front controller is implemented using the MVP pattern.

Comment: maybe you can help me out to understand. I see it like this: I have MainView on which there is a buttton which can open SecondView and also i have a button on SecondView which opens ThirdView. So to me it should be like MainPresenter should use SecondPresenter on button click because SecondView is maintained by SecondPresenter. Same as ThirdView is maintained by ThirdPresenter and since it's opened from SecondView it (ThirdPresenter) should be used by SecondPresenter.

Comment: Typically the front controller and relevant presenter(s) would have the request dispatcher injected.  When you click on a button/menu that requires another view to open the associated presenter would be notified `_presenter.RequestSecondView()` and the presenter would dispatch the required request via the dispatcher, e.g. `_dispatcher.Send("SecondView")`.  Now, you probably do not want views popping up all over the show in this fashion as the navigation is somewhat wonky but for the sake of your example it is useful.

Comment: Just to add to my last comment: it is all about *coupling*.  Both the *direct* injection of presenters, along with subsequent method invocation, and the calls to an injected `IMessageDispatcher`, e.g., are logically performing the same function.  The only distinction is the coupling since the dispatcher adds a layer of indirection.

Comment: hmm to be honest i do not get it. Could you provide some example to your answer showing this based on what i written? Means if we have APresenter for AView and BPresenter to BView and also CPresenter for CView. The situation is on AView there is a button to open BView and on BView there is a button to open CView. Would be great to see how this can be done. At the mment i see it APresenter has dependency to AView and BPresenter and on BPresenter there is dependency to BView and CPresenter and last on CPresenter there is only CView

Comment: Adding an example would be somewhat cumbersome.  You could take a look at [this old commit](https://github.com/Shuttle/Shuttle.Abacus/tree/21e503f4c7496917e4fc2f72e854e46a3004d3dd) that included a custom composite UI.  Click the `Clone or download` button to get the zip.  Perhaps that could shed some light.  If you'd like to e-mail me you can find my details on my [blog](http://www.ebenroux.co.za/contact/).

Comment: sent please check